# Linking HDF5 library into Visual C++ DLL project: unresolved external symbol __imp__*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, hdf5

I'm building a plug-in with MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, and I would like to include capabilities from the [HDF5 library](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). I have tried both building HDF5 from source with CMake, and installing the precompiled library ([`HDF5-1.8.7_CMake_x86_shared.zip`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html) for VC 2008). For either build directory/method, I've modified my project property:

- C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories: add the `include` for HDF5
- Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: add the `lib` for HDF5

Here is a snippet of my DLL module:

```
#include "cpp/H5Cpp.h"

static IResult OnBeginDocument (IDocument pDoc)
{
  H5Fcreate("C:\\out.h5", H5F_ACC_EXCL, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

  return True;
}
```

Note that VC++ correctly parses the `.h` files to, e.g., visually show pop-up documentation for `H5Fcreate` when I hover my mouse over that snippet. My problem is that I cannot build the module that tries to use `H5Fcreate`. Here is the console output from my build attempts:

```
1>MyProject.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__H5Fcreate referenced in function "int __cdecl OnBeginDocument(struct IModuleStruct *)" (?OnBeginDocument@@YAHPAUIModuleStruct@@@Z)
1>MyProject.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__H5check_version referenced in function "int __cdecl OnBeginDocument(struct IModuleStruct *)" (?OnBeginDocument@@YAHPAUIModuleStruct@@@Z)
1>C:\MyProject\Release\MyProject.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Both methods of attempting to link in HDF5 (precompiled vs self-compiled, as described above) produce these exact same errors, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

---

Many thanks to @HasanKhan and @StevieG, these were helpful tips for n00bs like me. Just to follow up clearly, I did indeed need to add lib filepaths in Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies:

```
hdf5dll.lib
hdf5_cppdll.lib
```

I may need to add other lib files if I require other HDF5 features. Also, it turned out that I needed to copy the HDF5 DLLs (from `bin`) into my system directory (e.g., `C:\WINDOWS\System32\`) for the plugin to operate correctly at runtime. All good now, thanks!

Comment: In project settings > Linker > Input you need to add the name of the lib file that you want to link with.

Comment: Are you missing `extern "C"` or do you mean to export mangled names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: you should add the
  path to the directory containing the .lib file here
- Linker > General > Input: you should add the name of the .lib file here

Answer (score 1):

Check this things:

1. **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies** contains **hdf5.lib**
2. **Linker > General > Additional Libraries Directories** contains path to **lib** directory of your HDF5 installation
3. **C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories** contains path to **include** directory of your HDF5 installation
4. You **build configuration** match to installed HDF5 version (**32** or **64 bit**)
5. You add to **PATH** variable **bin** directory of your HDF5 installation

I think it's enough.