# Compiling a hdf5-project with static linking

Tags: c++, static-libraries, hdf5

I am trying to compile and link a project that uses the HDF5 library. I am using Windows 10, VS2015 (C++ compiler) and CMake. I run into problems during the linking and get a lot of errors like

> libhdf5_cpp.lib(H5Attribute.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H5open

I am compiling a 32-bit application and I use the 32-bit pre-build binaries of the HDF5 package. The linker is trying to link with the libhdf5_cpp.lib file (which should be the static library according to the HDF5 home page). I have tried both Release and Debug mode during compiling. I have also tried to link dynamically, which resulted in the same error messages.

I have spent quite some time with this now and I am unsure that I will solve this in a reasonable time by myself. Does anyone have any good suggestions on hot to proceed?

And yeah, the CMake script and compiling works well under Linux so I guess it is VS related in some way.

Comment: Just a quick check, I don't know which version of HDF5 you're using. Probably, you have done it, but have you carefully read and followed the HDF5 section on Visual Studio and Cmake and the setup?
https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/windows.html#cm-runapp  
And this?  
http://hdf4.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.10/hdf5-1.10.0-patch1/src/unpacked/release_docs/USING_HDF5_CMake.txt

Comment: Finally, I got it to compile. The solution was to link with szip.lib and zlib.lib as well. This is not written anywhere in the CMake instruction. However, it is written in the document concerning compiling with VS. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For my problem, 
First I download pre-build HDF5 for Windows 64. Visual Studio 2015
I found there is two type of .lib files
one begin with prefix "lib"  and another one wihtout prefix "lib"

[image]

which I do not understand the different.

In the begining, I linkined to all .lib file for C++
( do not use f90 fortran JAVA ... )

The compiler said there are duplicate symbol.
Then I linked only hdf5.lib ... hdf5_cpp.lib ( without word "lib") in front .
Then the compiler says "Undefied external symbol"
command on QT pro are

```
INCLUDEPATH +=   "C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include"
LIBS        += -L"C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib"

LIBS        += -lhdf5
LIBS        += -lhdf5_cpp
LIBS        += -lhdf5_hl
LIBS        += -lhdf5_hl_cpp
LIBS        += -lhdf5_tools
LIBS        += -lszip
LIBS        += -lzlib
```

...
which produced the same problem that you have. "COMPILE ERROR"

after that I link to
libhdf5.lib , libhdf5_cpp.lib... 
command on QT pro are

```
INCLUDEPATH +=   "C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include"
LIBS        +=   -L"C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib"
LIBS        += -llibhdf5
LIBS        += -llibhdf5_cpp
LIBS        += -llibhdf5_hl
LIBS        += -llibhdf5_hl_cpp
LIBS        += -llibhdf5_tools
LIBS        += -llibszip
LIBS        += -llibzlib
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be similar to the issue here:
[Linking HDF5 library into Visual C++ DLL project: unresolved external symbol __imp__*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397296/linking-hdf5-library-into-visual-c-dll-project-unresolved-external-symbol-i)
Thus following those steps suggested there which are similar to the ones I linked in the comment coming from the official HDF5 pages help?
Here I cite them again:
https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/windows.html#cm-runapp
http://hdf4.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.10/hdf5-1.10.0-patch1/src/unpacked/release_docs/USING_HDF5_CMake.txt