# Reading from HDF5 file linker issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hdfs, linker-errors, hdf5

I am trying to read HDF5 file, this's the first time I come across this file format so please bare with me. The issue that I am having right now is linking the hdf5 lib to my project on Visual Studio 2017.
This's what I've done so far:

1. Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies contains hdf5.lib
2. Linker > General > Additional Libraries Directories contains path to lib directory of my HDF5 installation
3. C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories contains path to include directory of my HDF5 installation
4. I've add to PATH variable bin directory of my HDF5 installation

Following the steps of the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397296/linking-hdf5-library-into-visual-c-dll-project-unresolved-external-symbol-i).

However, I still have the following linker errors when I try to build my project.

```
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl H5::DataSpace::DataSpace(int,unsigned __int64 const *,unsigned __int64 const *)" (??0DataSpace@H5@@QEAA@HPEB_K0@Z) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl H5::DataSpace::getSimpleExtentDims(unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)const " (?getSimpleExtentDims@DataSpace@H5@@QEBAHPEA_K0@Z) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl H5::DataSpace::~DataSpace(void)" (??1DataSpace@H5@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class H5::DataSet __cdecl H5::H5Location::openDataSet(char const *,class H5::DSetAccPropList const &)const " (?openDataSet@H5Location@H5@@QEBA?AVDataSet@2@PEBDAEBVDSetAccPropList@2@@Z) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum H5T_class_t __cdecl H5::AbstractDs::getTypeClass(void)const " (?getTypeClass@AbstractDs@H5@@QEBA?AW4H5T_class_t@@XZ) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class H5::DataSpace __cdecl H5::DataSet::getSpace(void)const " (?getSpace@DataSet@H5@@UEBA?AVDataSpace@2@XZ) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl H5::DataSet::read(void *,class H5::DataType const &,class H5::DataSpace const &,class H5::DataSpace const &,class H5::DSetMemXferPropList const &)const " (?read@DataSet@H5@@QEBAXPEAXAEBVDataType@2@AEBVDataSpace@2@2AEBVDSetMemXferPropList@2@@Z) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl H5::DataSet::~DataSet(void)" (??1DataSet@H5@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl H5::H5File::H5File(char const *,unsigned int,class H5::FileCreatPropList const &,class H5::FileAccPropList const &)" (??0H5File@H5@@QEAA@PEBDIAEBVFileCreatPropList@1@AEBVFileAccPropList@1@@Z) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl H5::H5File::close(void)" (?close@H5File@H5@@UEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl H5::H5File::~H5File(void)" (??1H5File@H5@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::DataSpace const & const H5::DataSpace::ALL" (?ALL@DataSpace@H5@@2AEBV12@EB)
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::FileAccPropList const & const H5::FileAccPropList::DEFAULT" (?DEFAULT@FileAccPropList@H5@@2AEBV12@EB)
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::FileCreatPropList const & const H5::FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT" (?DEFAULT@FileCreatPropList@H5@@2AEBV12@EB)
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::DSetMemXferPropList const & const H5::DSetMemXferPropList::DEFAULT" (?DEFAULT@DSetMemXferPropList@H5@@2AEBV12@EB)
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::DSetAccPropList const & const H5::DSetAccPropList::DEFAULT" (?DEFAULT@DSetAccPropList@H5@@2AEBV12@EB)
1>EigenExperiment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::PredType const & const H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT" (?NATIVE_FLOAT@PredType@H5@@2AEBV12@EB)
1>C:\Users\maxim\source\repos\EigenExperiment\x64\Debug\EigenExperiment.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "EigenExperiment.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Also, I've attached the code I'm using, just in case I missed something.
Any hep is highly appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <filesystem>
#include <math.h>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
using namespace H5;


int main()
{
    string ifn = "basler.h5";
    string datasetPath = "/face_g_tobii/data";

    // Open HDF5 file handle, read only
    H5File fp(ifn.c_str(), H5F_ACC_RDONLY);

    // access the required dataset by path name
    DataSet dset = fp.openDataSet(datasetPath.c_str());

    // get the dataspace
    DataSpace dspace = dset.getSpace();

    // get the dataset type class
    H5T_class_t type_class = dset.getTypeClass();
    // According to HDFView, this is a 32-bit floating-point

    // get the size of the dataset
    hsize_t rank;
    hsize_t dims[2];
    rank = dspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims, NULL); // rank = 1
    cout << "Datasize: " << dims[0] << endl; // this is the correct number of values

    // Define the memory dataspace
    hsize_t dimsm[1];
    dimsm[0] = dims[0];
    DataSpace memspace(1, dimsm);


    // create a vector the same size as the dataset
    vector<float> data;
    data.resize(dims[0]);
    cout << "Vectsize: " << data.size() << endl;


    float data_out[65341];
    for (int i = 0; i < 65341; i++)
    {
        data_out[i] = 0;
    }
    // pass pointer to the array (or vector) to read function, along with the data type and space.
    dset.read(data_out, PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace, dspace); // FAILS
    dset.read(data_out, PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, dspace);           // FAILS
    dset.read(data.data(), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace, dspace); // FAILS


    // close the HDF5 file
    fp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the external libraries should be named first, what worked for me was:

1.4 Select Linker->Input and beginning with the
"Additional Dependencies" line, enter the library names. The
external libraries should be listed first, followed by the HDF5
library, and then optionally the HDF5 High Level, Fortran or C++
libraries. For example, to compile a C++ application, enter:

```
      szip.lib zlib.lib hdf5.lib hdf5_cpp.lib
```

This's from the documentation of HDF5, which I completely overlooked :/

Answer (score 1):

i am trying with hdf5 for c++ on vs2019 and i did the stuff of adding
szip.lib zlib.lib hdf5.lib hdf5_cpp.lib but then i can´t find both libs szip and zlib. Of course i did "H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB" at preprocessor, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the project you built is the x64 version, I suggest you check whether the linked hdf5.lib is 32-bit or 64-bit? You should use the 64-bit hdf5.

And I suggest you could try to check whether the platform and the Configuration  selection in the property page is `x64` and `debug`.

[image]

I suggest you could select "All Platforms" for the platform and select "All Configurations" for the Configuration when changing the properties.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I was using the correct version. I just didn't link all external libraries which was required :)